# Spring Data jpa order by joined column

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am using Spring Boot for Microservices. I am creating entity relationship for below Oracle table using Spring Data jpa.

```
StudentCourse -
StudentId
CourseId  
StudentName

CourseDetais -
CourseId
CourseName
```

Below is my entity classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="StudentCourse")
Class StudentCourseEntity {
   @EmbededId
   private StudentCourseId id;
  
   @Column(name="StudentName")
   private String studentName;

   @ManytoOne(fetch=FetchType.Lazy, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
   @NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
   @JoinColumn(name="CourseId")
   private CourseDetailsEntity courseDetailsEntity;
}

@Embeddable
Class StudentCourseId {
  @Column(name="StudentId")
  private String studentId;
   
  @Column(name="CourseId")
  private String courseId;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="CourseDetais")
Class CourseDetailsEntity {
   @Id
   @Column(name="CourseId")
   private String courseId;
  
   @Column(name="CourseName")
   private String courseName;

   @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="courseDetailsEntity")
   private List<StudentCourseEntity> studentCourseEntity;
}
```

My Oracle SQL query is like below:

```
SELECT * FROM CourseDetais WHERE CourseId IN (SELECT DISTINCT CourseId FROM StudentCourse WHERE StudentId=:studentId) order by CourseName;
```

In order to implement above query in data JPA, I created repository class extending PagingAndSortingRepository for CourseDetaisEntity, tried like below:

```
option 1-
findDistinctByIdStudentId(String studentId, Pageable pageable); 
//this is throwing not a selected expression as in pageable, I am passing courseDetailsEntity.courseName in Sort.By of PageRequest.of

option 2- 
@Query("SELECT a FROM CourseDetaisEntity a WHERE courseId IN (SELECT DISTINCT courseId FROM StudentCourseEntity b WHERE studentId=:studentId) order by a.courseName")
```

Is this the right way of doing it? What is the most efficient way of achieving it?

Answer (score 0):

Option 2 is the way to go.

There is another way if you want to externalise your queries.

You need to create a folder named **META-INF** in resources and then create a file named **jpa-named-queries.properties** inside META-INF.

Then convert your sql query to hql. i.e
from

```
SELECT * FROM CourseDetais WHERE CourseId IN (SELECT DISTINCT CourseId FROM 
StudentCourse WHERE StudentId=:studentId) order by CourseName;
```

to

```
SELECT a FROM CourseDetaisEntity a WHERE courseId IN (SELECT DISTINCT courseId FROM StudentCourseEntity b WHERE studentId=:studentId) order by a.courseName
```

Then add this hql to jpa-named-queries.properties.

```
MyRepository.getCourseDetails = hql query
```

Where MyRepository is your repository class.

Then create the method in the **MyRepository** with the name **getCourseDetails**.
i.e

```
CourseDetaisEntity getCourseDetails(@Param("studentId") String studentId);
```

Now you can call this method and you hql will be executed that is mentioned in the properties files.